# Is there a way to know what public ip addresses my pc had last months or year?

Tags: ip, dhcp, ip-address, dhcp-server

Is there a way to know what public ip addresses my pc had last months or year ?

Are they saved somewhere ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ask your ISP, in many places they are required by law to keep this information.

Comment: Alternatively, if you posted on a forum, IP Addresses are stored on single posts. You can ask a forum administrator with what IP you posted a post and they usually can look it up. It does depend on the forumsoftware, and whether you use IPv4 or IPv6, but that is another way to find out in case your ISP is not cooperating.

Comment: Ok thank you guys, apparently there is no efficient way to gather this information. This is not saved nor in the router nor in the pc. I have to ask either isp, or check sites where I posted, or maybe mails I sent.